# Lookup field in DRF make it case insensitive

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, case-insensitive

I currently have something like this

```
class GetUsernameUnique_RetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = modelEmployer.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'user__username'
    serializer_class = Serializer_ListEmployer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
```

However it seems the username in lookup field is case sensitive. Any idea how I can make it case insensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`iexact`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact)

```
lookup_field = 'user__username__iexact'
```

Comment: But then you need to look it up using `'user__username__iexact'` which is not ideal. What if you want to user `username` as a lookup but you also want that to be case insensitive?

Comment: The **`i`** stands for ***case insensitive***

Comment: I know, I'm saying the lookup will then need to be `api/user__username__iexact`, a more elegant solution would be to just use `username` and translate that to a case insensitive lookup internally. This is an implementation detail that the consumer of the API should not know about.

Comment: This worked for me, but note that if you change the value of "lookup_field", you must also change the name of the corresponding url kwarg to match.  So here the route for this view in "urls.py" would change from `path('<slug:user__username>/')` to  `path('<slug:user__username__iexact>/')`. If you don't do this, you'll get an error.  As a side note: This might be what @Nobilis was objecting to above, but I didn't really understand their objection.  But if anyone else likes this solution and wants to follow it, perhaps this comment will help to clarify it a little more.

Comment: Just to add...this also works for the other common filter words, so you can use user__username__icontains :)